# Custom register controller in FOSUserBundle does not return errors

Tags: php, symfony, overriding, registration, fosuserbundle

I'm using FOSUB in my Symfony app to to manage my users. I overrided the register template and controller to use Ajax and customize some stuff. It works fine if the user proceeds to registration with no errors. But if something is wrong (ex. different paswwords) the `$form->isValid()` returns false but the `$form->getErrors()` array is empty. After some research I still don't know how to retrieves those errors. Anyone got an idea ? Thanks :)
Here is my controller:

```
public function registerAction(Request $request)
{
    if($request->isXmlHttpRequest())
    {
        $returnArray = array();
        /** @var $formFactory \FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FactoryInterface */
        $formFactory = $this->container->get('fos_user.registration.form.factory');
        /** @var $userManager \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface */
        $userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
        /** @var $dispatcher \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface */
        $dispatcher = $this->container->get('event_dispatcher');

        $user = $userManager->createUser();
        $user->setEnabled(true);

        $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE, $event);

        if (null !== $event->getResponse()) {
            return $event->getResponse();
        }

        $form = $formFactory->createForm();
        $form->setData($user);

        if ('POST' === $request->getMethod()) {
            $form->bind($request);

            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
                $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS, $event);
                $userManager->updateUser($user);

                if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
                    $returnArray[] = array("success" => "Registration confirmed.");
                    $returnArray[] = array("info" => "An email has been send.");
                }

                    $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));

                return new Response(json_encode($returnArray));
            }
            else
            {
                foreach($form->getErrors() as $error)
                    $returnArray[] = array("error" => $error->getMessage());

                return new Response(json_encode($returnArray));
            }
        }
    }
    return new Response("This is not XHR");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the error of the password fields you must display the errors on the password field. **{{ form_errors(form.plainPassword.first) }}**. If you just do {{ form_errors(form.plainPassword) }} the errors are not returning because the errors aren't bubbling.

Comment: Thanks, I knew this method :). My problem is how can I get these errors in my controller ? (e.i. `$form->getField('password')->getErrors();` )

Comment: I was able to access the password errors in controller via $form->createView()->children['temporaryPassword']->children['pass']->vars['errors'];

You cannot access errors via $form->get('password')->children... because public you've no methods or properties that allows you access, so you need to access via the FormView class.

Hope it can help you

Comment: Your method works fine but I did not use that way and I had other errors in my code. But actually this is a good way thanks :).
For the other viewers, here is my method. In the FormBuilder I set the option `error_bubbling` to `true` for each field. This way errors are send back to the parent (i.e the form) and are accessible in `$form->getErrors()`. Hope it will help.

Comment: Your way is much better than mine if you can overwrite the Form Type ;)